# ParametricPlot problems

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, plotting

I have the following code:

```
$Assumptions -> {b = 1, Element[r, reals], r > 0}


gtt[r_] := -((r + b)/(r - 3 b))^((-3/2)) (r^2 + 6 b r + 21 b^2)
grr[r_] := ((r + b)/(r - 3 b))^(3/2) (r^2 + 6 b r + 21 b^2)^-1
g[r_] := -(((r + b)/(r - 3 b))^(3/2) (r - 3 b)^2)^2

B[r_] := ((gtt[r])^-1 (grr[r])^-1 Sqrt[-g[r]])
p[r_] = D[B[r], r]
q[r_] := ((grr[r])^-1 Sqrt[-g[r]])
z[r] = Integrate[-(gtt[r])^-1, r]
ParametricPlot[{{V[r]}, {z[r]}}, {r, -100, 100}]

V[r_] = 3/4 (B[r])^-2 (gtt[r])^2 (p[r])^2 - 
1/2 (B[r])^-1 (gtt[r])^2 D[p[r], r] - 
1/2 (B[r])^-2 (gtt[r]) D[q[r], r] p[r]
```

I have two questions:

$1:$ I evaluated the integral (I will not post the result as it was very long and complicated), but when I tried to use the limits(r to infinity), the integral would not evaluate, however when I just gave the command to integrate without the limits it gave me a result. Why did this happen and will it be the correct result?

$2:$ I want to use ParametricPlot to plot $V[z]$ but so far I am unsuccessful and I am unsure if it is because of a problem with the integral or because I am implementing ParametricPlot incorrectly. What I tried is this

```
ParametricPlot[{{V[r]},{z[r]}},{r,-100,100}]
```

I also tried it the other way around but either way I get a graph appearing but nothing being plotted on it. Also the range of the graph is always between 1 and -1.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show your code. It will make it easier for people to check it and suggest solutions. The `ParametricPlot` command is not correct as written. It requires two functions, say $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, to produce an $xy$ plot with parameter $t$. Your $V(r)$ also contains the undefined functions $B$ and $p$.

Comment: Is the code given in terms of `Mathematia' syntax? If not, please provide a MMA code.

Comment: `\frac{3}{4}` is no Mathematica code!

Comment: I.e., what they're saying is they'd be happy to help, but they want you to do your part, which means: (a) present all your code as Mathematica code; e.g., ` \frac{r + b}{r - 3 b}` is LaTeX; `(r+b)/(r-3 b)` is Mathematica; (b) fix the unmatched parentheses in `g[r_]`; and (c) give the exact code for the *definite* integral (i.e., with the limits) that you say wouldn't evaluate.

Comment: Hello, sorry I was away for a week and so have been unable to update. I have chaged that now I hope it is a little clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seriously need to go through the documentation. There are some very trivial mistakes (maybe typo!)

Apart from that, only tricks you need here is to use `Re` for `V[r]` and scale it properly to make it look good.

```
b = 1
gtt[r_] := -((r + b)/(r - 3 b))^((-3/2)) (r^2 + 6 b r + 21 b^2)
grr[r_] := ((r + b)/(r - 3 b))^(3/2) (r^2 + 6 b r + 21 b^2)^-1
g[r_] := -(((r + b)/(r - 3 b))^(3/2) (r - 3 b)^2)^2
B[r_] := ((gtt[r])^-1 (grr[r])^-1 Sqrt[-g[r]])
p[r_] = D[B[r], r];
q[r_] := ((grr[r])^-1 Sqrt[-g[r]])
z[r_] = Integrate[-(gtt[r])^-1, r];
V[r_] = 3/4 (B[r])^-2 (gtt[r])^2 (p[r])^2 
        - 1/2 (B[r])^-1 (gtt[r])^2 D[p[r], r] 
        - 1/2 (B[r])^-2 (gtt[r]) D[q[r], r] p[r];

ParametricPlot[Re@{V[r]/10^5, z[r]}, {r, -100, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I am very new to mathematica, I only began using it this month so I have a lot to learn! Just so I know, what trivial mistakes to you mean exactly?

Comment: @Claire.Bear, its fine. We all have our first time. My first question was eventually removed after some time (it was dumb :p). 

I got some error when I copied your initial question (for example you used `reals` not `Reals`) and I wrote the lines from scratch.  But probably they are typos - so don't worry. Always keep your eyes open for Caps and brackets. Enjoy :)